# Go to a specific jsp page after authentication (spring security)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have 3 type of users in my application, and every user has a his own jsp page. I want that after authentication, every user is redirect to his "own" page, how can this be done?

I'm using spring security and i'm novice.

Comment: 'every user has his own jsp page' doesn't make any sense for me. You cannot have a differen page for each user. You need a `profile` page where you can show the information about the logged user.

Comment: i would discourage your proposed solution simply because you will need to create a new jsp page for every new user of your application and update your web-app. try the suggestion made by @IgnazioC

Comment: Why not have a fixed page, but that will then redirect to the specific page?

Comment: Thank you guys for your response.
i didn't start the application from scratch,I'm just adding my part,I have only 3 types of users:A,B  and C(the number of users is steady)
Your answer is intersting @Taliman but i prefer the the rederiction is automatic in the moment of authentication.

Comment: the number of users type is steady*

Answer (score 1):

You can **redefine the Spring Security Authentication Success Handler**

Create one class implementing AuthenticationSuccessHandler :

```
public class RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
//Store the role and destination url relationship 
private static Map<String, String>  ROLE_URL_MAP    = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
static {
    ROLE_URL_MAP.put("ROLE_AUDIT", "/private/auditindex.do");
    ROLE_URL_MAP.put("ROLE_USER", "/private/userindex.do");
    ROLE_URL_MAP.put("ROLE_ADMIN", "/private/adminindex.do");
}

private static String               DEFAULT_URL     = "/private/home.do";

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
        //obtain the userDetails
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        //rediret to destination url
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + getTargetUrl(userDetails));
    } else {
        //rediret to default url
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + DEFAULT_URL);
    }

}

/** 
 * get de target Url for roluser
 * @param userDetails userDetails
 * @return target url after login
 */
public static String getTargetUrl(UserDetails userDetails) {
    String role = userDetails.getAuthorities().isEmpty() ? null : userDetails.getAuthorities().toArray()[0].toString();
    String targetUrl = ROLE_URL_MAP.get(role);
    if (targetUrl != null) {
        return targetUrl;
    } else {
        return DEFAULT_URL;
    }
}
}
```

If you use xml-confi, you define your bean:

```
<beans:bean id="redirectRoleStrategy" class="xxx.xxx.RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

and

```
<security:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="redirectRoleStrategy">
```

But if you use java-config include in the *WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().successHandler(new RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jorge Jiménez Barra,I will test it as soon as possible and I will give you a feedback.